# why are there are so many svchost established connections to Isilon?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, tcpip, netstat, isilon

Our client has a Isilon (used only for smb) with few nodes attached to it. When I run TCPView I don't understand why svchost service established the connection and why there're so many of them:

[image]

And the ip 10.64.4.212:

[image]

I run svchost analyzer to see what is the exact service behind and the result is:

Then when I connect to the other client's server with the same OS Win2012R2 and Isilon I don't see these connections. Can somebody tell if there's something wrong? Why there're so many established connections by svchost to Isilon?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell that it's RPC traffic because of the connections to the RPC endpoint mapper on TCP port 135 and subsequent connections to a high-numbered port, e.g. 48471.

You can use [portqry](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009) and query the RPC endpoint mapper on the remote device yourself, and see what RPC endpoint is registered on port 48471. My guess is that it's going to be something [SAM-R](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245476.aspx) related, for example to do username/group membership lookups.

This should also be apparent in a network trace. (Netmon, Wireshark, netsh.exe)

Comment: Thanks. Using your guides I found out that is RPC for Isilon Witness Service.